# razor: model that is returned on post does not contain changed data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have this page:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("SaveIndex")" method="POST" id="idForm">
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name[0])       
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AutoCloseWindow)
    <div class="divEditColumns">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td>
                    <div class="Column Column100">
                        <div class="divFieldGroup">
                            <div class="GroupHeadline">Übersetzung</div>
                            <div class="GroupContent">
                                <table cellspacing="" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="Label">
                                            <label for="">language</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="Field">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="@Model.Name[0]" />
                                            <div class="input-control text">
                                                <input type="text" name="name2" value="@Model.Name[0]" />
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

It displays data from my model and a field on which I can alter the Name value.

Now when I press save this method is fired and my model is returned:

```
public ActionResult SaveIndex(GlobalTaggingLocalizationModel model, bool autoclosewindow = false)
{
   
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { autoclosewindow = autoclosewindow, refreshOpener = true, id = 0 });
}
```

But the model contains the values from the DB (original values that were put onto the model) and my changes to the model are not passed here. I must be forgetting one simple thing

Best,

J

Comment: Can you give an example ? What's your change ?

Comment: I have see your last question is about `string name`, but you deleted that. Have you solve it ?

Comment: Do you do some change at `<input type="text" name="name2" value="@Model.Name[0]" />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the text `name2`, you need to keep the `name attribute` is same as the model property.

try:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" value="@Model.Name[0]" />
```

result:

[image]

Comment: you got it! it was the name attribute that was missing! thank you!